# AppCenter will not show non-free apps on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: release-hera, appcenter

I'm asking this in hopes someone here has gotten their RPi4 working with eOS. I was able to get it going with 18.04 server, USB boot and WiFi. eOS installed and runs great!

I only have (now) one issue.

**AppCenter will not show non-free apps.** Monitor and AppEditor are the two that come to mind. I was able to build the latter from github, but its an overall issue.

I feel like this is something simple I overlooked. Not looking for a hand out and I realize it's not "stock", but any advice would be appreciated.

Thank you.

edit - sound fixed with `dtparam=audio=on`

edit - wifi fixed by commenting out the info added to `50-cloud-init.yaml` so ubuntu server could get online.